# What does "grep myname /etc/passwd >& /dev/null" mean?

Tags: shell, redirect

I saw this code in the example in shell scripting book.

case 1.
grep myname `/etc/passwd > /dev/null` means grep myname in file /etc/passwd but no output to screen.

case 2.
grep myname `/etc/passwd >&2` means grep myname in file /etc/passwd and output to std err.

case 3.
`grep myname /etc/passwd >& /dev/null`

What is the meaning of "&" right after redirection > in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, it means both `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

It's just like:

```
cmd >& file
```

is equivalent to

```
cmd >file 2>&1
```

but the former is `bash` and `csh` only

You have also a special `bash` syntax to pipe both `STDERR` and `STDOUT`:

```
<STDIN> |& <PROCESS STDOUT|STDERR>
```